# Excel sort issue on cell change with copy paste

Tags: vba, excel

I cant understand why this is happening!

I have created a 'top 10' reasons on a dashboard. In the background when the date parameters of the dashboard are changed by altering dates in some cells I want the sub to sort the full list of reasons and return the top 10.

I made the sub (quite lazily using the recorder) and it works perfectly. I then setup a sub to check for the date cells being changed and call my sorter and although the copy and paste is working... the sort is not...

I am wondering if this is a timing issue? Perhaps when the sub is being called the formulas and cells haven't updated?

So here is my quick and dirty top10 sub

```
Sub Stage1ReasonUpdate()

Sheets("Lists").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("R4:R52"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists").Sort
    .SetRange Range("Q4:S52")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


Sheets("Lists").Select
Range("Q4:Q13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Stage1").Select
Range("U16").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Stage1").Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

and here is the sub that is on the worksheet checking for changes

```
Private Sub Worksheet1_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("r3:w3")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    'MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    Call Stage1ReasonUpdate


End If
End Sub
```

I am just hitting a blank and I want to understand why it works when the sub is called directly but not when called from the worksheet change.

Thank you in advance for any help you give

Comment: FYI, `Target` is already a Range, so you can just do `Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target)`.

Comment: I just copied the code from MSDN and it worked so I hadnt looked at refinement. The more pressing issue is working out why this code works one way and not the other. But I did make the change you suggested

Comment: No answers on this, anyone? bueller?